# Divide two 64-bit numbers and store the result in a float without losing precision

Tags: c, precision

Let's say you have a very large 64-bit value measuring time in microseconds. I want to convert that to a float, measured in seconds, which means dividing the time value by 1000000. In what order can you perform the divide and conversion without losing data?

If I perform the division first, it's still an integer, and I lose the sub-second portion of the measurement. If I convert the value to float first, the measurement gets truncated from 64-bit to 24-bits, and the result is incorrect.

Is the compiler smart enough to know what to do if you perform both operations at once? Or does this require manually breaking it up into pieces?

*I understand that I may still lose precision in the final float by dividing down so far, and that is fine. I want to avoid any extra loss due to the way the conversion is performed.*

Comment: "and the result is incorrect" - how so?

Comment: If I cast a 64-bit integer to a 32-bit float, it will overflow. Performing the division after that point will be dividing a wrong (overflowed) value.

Comment: Why don't you use a double? A float has only 23 bits precision, a double has 52 bits precision.

Comment: Casting a 64-bit integer to a 32-bit float won't overflow, anyway. It'll lose precision, but it won't overflow.

Comment: with an extended float you wont lose any precision.

Comment: Thinking about a division by a constant value (`1000000`) as a division can be confusing. Think about that operation as a multiplication by the value's inversion (`0.000001`).

Comment: I'm assuming/guessing that you're using the 64 bit number for benchmarking. And, the number comes from converting `gettimeofday/timeval` or `clock_gettime/timespec` to the `long long`. When I do this, I'm usually interested in a difference [of `end_time - start_time`]. I keep the numbers in the `long long` and only convert the difference to a `double` when printing (e.g. `printf("ELAPSED: %.9f\n",usec_to_sec(dif));` with: `double usec_to_sec(long long usec)`

Comment: @ndim: Changing to a multiplication is not a good approach. 1,000,000 is exactly representable in binary floating-point (both IEEE-754 binary32, often used for `float`, and in binary64, often used for `double`). So, given some `x`, we can convert `x` to floating-point and divide by exactly 1,000,000, and have only the errors caused by the conversion of `x` and the division. However, .000001 is not exactly representable. So we cannot multiply it; we can only multiply by a nearby number, the one that results from converting .000001 to floating-point. That introduces unnecessary error.

Comment: If you convert the number of microseconds to a `double` (using IEEE-754 binary64) and divide that by 1,000,000, you will have two small rounding errors, a total error bounded by about 1 part in 2^−52. That is is an accuracy better than one microsecond per century. Is the clock measuring these microseconds that accurate to start with?

Comment: *"very large 64-bit value measuring time in microseconds"*. That would be over 200,000 years. What is the actual time that you're measuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention 24 bits, I assume you are using [single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) floating point numbers (`float`). Use [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) and you will get a 53 bit mantissa. That should be enough for a number of microseconds, otherwise use [`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) and you will get a 63 bit mantissa with gcc on x86-64.

Comment: 80 bits is the size of the *whole* long double, not the size of the mantissa.

Comment: extended precision gives a 63 bit fraction plus the integer bit.

Comment: Thanks both of you, answer fixed.

Comment: Yes, using double precision is the correct answer. 2^53 microseconds is about 280 years. That's plenty for any practical purpose.